# skmaps sdktools integration

Tags: ios, xcode, skmaps

I am integrating skobbler maps in my project. I were looking at the SDKTools. Is it necessary to integrate SDKTools to have navigation feature in the app. If yes, I were integrating it using Xcode 6.1 but it shows me error duplicate symbols for arm64 and also

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKTNavigationUtils", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MapsViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am following this link: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/iosTools

Please help me as I am stuck. Spend two whole days only for integration

Comment: are you integrating SDKTools via cocoapods or grabbing it from the demo project?

Comment: Grabbing it from Demo Project...I am following "How to" for SDK Tools given on getting started guides of Skobbler

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to integrate SDKTools to have navigation feature in the application, just the SDK is enough.

Also based on the steps from the website, skmaps developers created a demo app using the SDKTools for navigation. You can find it at the following link: 
http://www1.skobbler.com/iphonebuilds/20150107/SDKToolsIntegrationDemo.zip

The "duplicate symbols for arm64 " error can be caused by these reasons:

1. Declaring constants with the same name as we have in the SDKTools
   (will be fixed in the next release).
2. The same file is added in the project twice.